# Stata moving products

Tags: stata

Using Stata I want a formula (line of code) that takes all of the previous entries for a given group G at a given cell and returns the product for all of the values at that cell and above. For example:

```
G    X    Y
1    1    1
1    2    2
1    6    12
1    3    36
2    2    2
2    4    8
3    2    2
4    2    2
4    11   22 
4    7    154
```

G = Group ID, X = Value, Y = Moving Product

The way I have been doing this is pretty long and involves creating a good number of variables. There must be a way in Stata to just have it do a moving product by group ID (G).

Any insight is helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
sort G 
by G: gen moving_product = exp(sum(ln(X)))
```

This should make X = Y

Comment: Your solution depends on `G` already being `sort`ed, but that is easy. A more delicate point is that the default numeric data type `float` may not be suitable here; I would always use `double`.